# Error While installing any libararies in node in MACOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I tried installing Typescript, Angular in npm, as i have also installed node.js from website and checked all the registry but it is still not working. Any Suggestions are welcome.

```
% npm install -f @angular/cli

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxyname
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/amandeep/.npm/_logs/2021-11-25T09_23_23_706Z-debug.log


-----after running. the downloaded ------
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
See "/private/var/folders/13/zj_h6wvj4cl_l9q7zzs97b8c0000gn/T/ng-S5Rfen/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Comment: Please include the error message as text rather than as an image, as those of us using screenreaders won't be able to read it otherwise.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Added the comment

Comment: The error suggest you might have a proxy up and running in your terminal, one that doesnt work

Comment: any solution @e

Comment: any Solutiion @Evert

Comment: Yes, try removing your proxy settings if possible!

Comment: How did you install Node? (Please mention that at the start of your post, so people know whether you installed node+npm correctly to begin with. If you didn't, any errors alter on are red herrings and the solution is "install node properly, and don't install npm separately")

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 
I havve tried uninstalling clearing cache as well and also i have installed again the npm node and angular but in cas of angular the project is not getting created fully as it stops in between and if i try to run already made angular code by "ng serve" it shows

Comment: that doesn't answer the question I asked. _How_ did you install Node? Did you use brew? `nvm`? Custom compile? And to quote myself: "_Please mention that at the start of your post_, so people know whether you installed node+npm correctly to begin with"

Comment: Also, why is that `-f` in your install call?

Comment: @amandeepchandel is my email, Please ping. Will Share Screen